# APNS Gateway Message Error

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

I am new to IOS development and I was trying to implement APNS. It was working fine until suddenly it started to give this error after sending the notifications form Node backend.

`{ [GatewayMessageError: Invalid token] message: 'Invalid token', code: 8, identifier: 0 }`

Any leads would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Was the format of the notification changed such that it is possibly not a valid JSON string anymore? Please show some message causing the error response.

Comment: Nope everything is exactly the same. Absolutely no change.

Comment: Please show some message causing the error anyway.

Comment: This is the exact msg thats coming @Codor

Comment: No, I meant what kind of message does your server component send before the error is reported?

Comment: agent.connect shows that it is active. 
agent.createMessage().send passes the msg without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is such a strange Problem. I am using apnagent in Node.js to send notifications. This error occurred to me and then it solved on its own. I am still confused as to how it is solved as i did not change anything in my code. From what I have read, this might be due to apnagent's irregularity or non performance.